Failed HTTPS requests to NGINX server
I am trying to set up Https for my Ubuntu server using Nginx. I am running an application on localhost and using reverse proxy. This is my first time using Linux and nginx. My https request is failing everytime.
I will try to include as many relevant details from the server:
I have assigned a domain name to my site and have configured the ssl certificates using certbot.
When I make a request using http, it is successful:
curl request to http port 
However, https requests always fail:
curl request to https port
Both ports 443 and 80 are active and listening:
active ports
In order to make debugging simple I have now configured nginx to redirect http requests(port 80) to https (port 443). This means requests made to my http now also fail.
This is my site's configuration file now:
nginx conf file
The following is a snippet of the nginx debug log after I made an https request:
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http script copy: "https://"
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http script var: "chatbot.sweatsupport.site"
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http script var: "/ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PGEXYJx"
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http finalize request: 301, "/ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PGEXYJx" a:1, c:1
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http special response: 301, "/ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PGEXYJx"
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 http set discard body
2024/12/28 18:27:40 [debug] 21424#21424: *207 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2024 18:27:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://chatbot.sweatsupport.site/ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PGEXYJx

What I have interpreted from the log is that a 301 http response is made. There seems to be no upstream logs showing any requests to localhost:8000.
I do attempt to understand the log but that lead to more confusions so I will not mention that.
I have been stuck on this error for 3 days and have browsed the most forums I could but to no avail. Please do let me know if you need any more information. I would be grateful for any advice.

what error do you get if you curl against http://localhost:8000 ? Can you change proxy_pass http://localhost:8000 to proxy_pass http://localhost  and restart nginx and try again using https? It seems like https connection are redirecting to localhost:8000

proxy_pass should be set to whatever port your app is running. since localhost worked before setting up ssl then means your app is running on port 80. so proxy_pass http://localhost should be valid. Test it

for 3 days in that three days, did you test without the proxy? Did it work? Info 101.

PowerShell curl command isn’t the real one. You’d better use your Ubuntu terminal to execute curl and also enable its logging to dig further into the issue. Alternatively, OpenSSL command line can be used to debug HTTPS issues.
